# ListFragment onListItemClick multiple functionality

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I currently have an alarm clock app that saves all the alarms into an array and then displays them in a custom list view. When the list view is clicked the app goes to a separate screen to edit the alarm. I now want to add delete functionality to the app.

My current idea is to have a delete and edit button above the list view and when a user clicks one of the buttons the functionality of the list view will change accordingly. So if they click edit, then whichever alarm they click will go to the edit screen. And if they click delete, the alarm they click will be deleted from the array.

Code below shows the `OnListItemClick` method (which currently goes to the edit screen) and my `OnClick` method for my two buttons:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //pass the alarm name as a string to the activity
    String name = savedAlarmArray[position].getmName();

    listItemCallback.onEditAlarmSelected(name);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.delete_button:
            // Now the onListItemClick will delete the alarm;


            break;
        case R.id.edit_button:
            // Now the onListItemClick will edit the alarm;
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious about your design choice. Why not go with a more standard option that users are more likely to understand? For example adding a delete button to the edit page, using a contextual action bar to offer the delete button, or using gestures allowing users to swipe the list item to delete the alarm.

Comment: You can add the delete option using onItemLongClickListener

Comment: I am pretty new to Android and haven't worked with an action bar yet. I am going to read about it and most likely implement it based off these answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question how to delete the items in a list? Seems like you have a plan that will work fine for changing the action of the listener.

On an aside, I would recommend looking at the [Android Developer guide on ActionBars and Contexual ActionBars.](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look for a more user friendly way to do this but here you go.

```
private boolean editMode = false;
...

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //pass the alarm name as a string to the activity
    String name = savedAlarmArray[position].getmName();
    if(editMode){
        listItemCallback.onEditAlarmSelected(name);
    } else {
        //delete
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.delete_button:
            // Now the onListItemClick will delete the alarm;
            editMode = false;
            break;
        case R.id.edit_button:
            // Now the onListItemClick will edit the alarm;
            editMode = true;
            break;

    }
}
```